# Using PHP stripos() in Logical Filtering

Tags: php

How can i use the stripos to filter out unwanted word existing on itself. 
How do i twist the code below that a search for '`won`' in grammar will not return true, since '`wonderful`' is another word itself.

```
$grammar = 'it is a wonderful day';
$bad_word = 'won';

$res = stripos($grammar, $bad_word,0);

if($res === true){
       echo 'bad word present';
}else{
       echo 'no bad word'; 
}

//result  'bad word present'
```

Comment: Have you tried preg_match()? Or adding a space to the start/end of your variable? Since you are looking for the word `won`, it stands to reason that it should have a space to the left OR right of it when contained in a sentence.

Comment: Thank you i think preg_match() would work                                                                                                         if (preg_match("/\bwon\b/i", "it is a wonderful day")) {
    echo "bad word was found.";
} else {
    echo "bad word not found.";
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               //bad word not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $grammar = 'it is a wonderful day';
 $bad_word = 'won';

        /*  \b   \b indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct won not wonderful is  searched   */

 if(preg_match("/\bwon\b/i","it is a wonderful day")){ 
    echo "bad word was found";} 
 else { 
    echo "bad word not found"; 
    } 

//result is : bad word not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)

```
$grammar = 'it is a wonderful day';
$bad_word = 'won';
$pattern = "/ +" . $bad_word . " +/i"; 

// works with one ore more spaces around the bad word, /i means it's not case sensitive

$res = preg_match($pattern, $grammar);
// returns 1 if the pattern has been found

if($res == 1){
  echo 'bad word present';
}
else{
  echo 'no bad word'; 
}
```